# Levene test of 1 quantitative variables and 2 qualitative variables

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I am trying to run a levene test and also a t test  of 1 numerical variable (`LungCap`) and 2 qualitative variables (`Smoke` and `Gender`). `Smoke` and `Gender` each have their own column.  Can I just paste a new column combining the gender and the smoking and then run the levene test?  I tried that and it gave me this error:

```
Error in t.test.formula(LungCap ~ GenderSmoke, data = hwdata, var.equal = T) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

We are trying to figure out the difference in lung capacity among women smoking vs men smoking

This is hwdata table

```
hwdata
    LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean GenderSmoke
415   8.125  10   66.8    no   male        no     male no
463   7.125  10   60.2    no   male        no     male no
179   9.850  17   72.4   yes female       yes  female yes
526   8.350  11   68.1    no   male        no     male no
195  11.225  16   72.8    no   male        no     male no
118  10.275  18   71.0    no   male        no     male no
299   2.625   5   49.0    no   male        no     male no
229   4.700   3   52.7    no   male        no     male no
244   8.600  12   61.6    no   male       yes     male no
14    6.000  10   61.1    no female        no   female no
374  10.725  16   77.4    no female        no   female no
665  10.400  16   69.6    no   male        no     male no
602  11.800  19   74.6    no female        no   female no
603   9.375  15   73.1    no female        no   female no
709   6.900  15   64.5    no female        no   female no
91    6.950   9   63.9    no   male       yes     male no
348   5.025  12   55.0    no female        no   female no
649   6.825  13   60.2    no   male        no     male no
355   7.575  12   61.5    no female        no   female no
26    8.350  12   61.3    no   male       yes     male no
```

Here is what I have:

```
LungCapData <- read.delim(file="LungCapData.txt")

# WE will use a t-test so we need select a sample from LungCapData 
set.seed(123) 
hwdata <- LungCapData[sample(x =rownames(LungCapData), size=20 ), ]
hwdata$GenderSmoke <- paste(hwdata$Gender, hwdata$Smoke, sep=" ")
table(hwdata$GenderSmoke)
hwdata

# Evaluation of homogeneity of variance (Levene's test)
library (car)
leveneTest(LungCap ~ GenderSmoke, hwdata, center=mean)
```

Comment: And what about the same question but instead it would be  for nonsmoker males vs nonsmoker females?

Answer (score 1):

The question is on the Levene test and the t test giving an error has nothing to do with the question title. The new variable `GenderSmoke` has 4 levels and there is no such thing as a 4 samples t test. In one of the code comments it is written

> WE will use a t-test so we need select a sample from LungCapData

Why is this? If you have more data, use it. But this would be a question about statistics, not about R code.

A more useful test would be a chi-squared test for independence of the two variables, `Gender` and `Smoke`. In the code below, with no `male, yes` in the data the p-values are simulated.

As for the Levene test, there is no error but since the question also asks about the use of `paste` to create `GenderSmoke`, here is a R way, with `help("interaction")`.

```
library(car)

chisq_tbl <- table(hwdata[c("Gender", "Smoke")])
chisq_tbl
#        Smoke
#Gender   no yes
#  female  7   1
#  male   12   0

chisq.test(chisq_tbl, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
#
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on
#   2000 replicates)
#
#data:  chisq_tbl
#X-squared = 1.5789, df = NA, p-value = 0.3938
```

There are reasons to assume independence of `Gender` and `Smoke` but with only one `Smoke == "yes"`, the tests results are not reliable.
And now the Levene test.

```
hwdata <- within(hwdata, GS <- interaction(Gender, Smoke))

leveneTest(LungCap ~ GS, hwdata, center = mean)
#Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = mean)
#      Df F value Pr(>F)
#group  2  0.9758  0.397
#      17
```

The null of homogeneity of variance is not rejected.

**Data in `dput` format**

```
hwdata <-
structure(list(LungCap = c(8.125, 7.125, 9.85, 8.35, 11.225, 
10.275, 2.625, 4.7, 8.6, 6, 10.725, 10.4, 11.8, 9.375, 6.9, 6.95, 
5.025, 6.825, 7.575, 8.35), Age = c(10L, 10L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 
18L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 15L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 
12L, 12L), Height = c(66.8, 60.2, 72.4, 68.1, 72.8, 71, 49, 52.7, 
61.6, 61.1, 77.4, 69.6, 74.6, 73.1, 64.5, 63.9, 55, 60.2, 61.5, 
61.3), Smoke = c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no"), Gender = c("male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male"
), Caesarean = c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", 
"no", "yes"), GenderSmoke = c("male no", "male no", "female yes", 
"male no", "male no", "male no", "male no", "male no", "male no", 
"female no", "female no", "male no", "female no", "female no", 
"female no", "male no", "female no", "male no", "female no", 
"male no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("415", "463", 
"179", "526", "195", "118", "299", "229", "244", "14", "374", 
"665", "602", "603", "709", "91", "348", "649", "355", "26"))
```

Comment: Thank you and what about the t-test, I tried using the same format but it gave me an error: grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                             
t.test(LungCap ~ GS, data=hwdata, var.equal = T)

Comment: @NoobinR That is the first thing I wrote in my answer, you cannot run a 4 samples t.test, only a 1 or 2 samples t.test. If you have the interactions between 2 binary variables, you will have 2*2 = 4 levels, a t.test will *never* be applicable. You can run t.tests on each of those variables, say, `t.test(LungCap ~ Smoke, hwdata)`. Or with the formula `LungCap ~ Gender`.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I thought.  I am going to have to either create new tables or subset the data to make this feasible.

Comment: `simulate.p.value = TRUE` which this is required ?

Comment: @kcm Because there are zero `male == "yes"` in the data.